# Expected an empty string comparison to return false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to solve the CodeWars code challenge [The Hashtag Generator](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52449b062fb80683ec000024/train/javascript)
:

> The marketing team is spending way too much time typing in hashtags.
> Let's help them with our own Hashtag Generator!
>
> Here's the deal:
>
> - It must start with a hashtag (`#`).
> - All words must have their first letter capitalized.
> - If the final result is longer than 140 chars it must return `false`.
> - If the input or the result is an empty string it must return `false`.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> " Hello there thanks for trying my Kata"  =>  "#HelloThereThanksForTryingMyKata"
> "    Hello     World   "                  =>  "#HelloWorld"
> ""                                        =>  false
> ```

This is my code:

```javascript
function generateHashtag (str) {
   if (str == "") {return false;}
   else
     {
      let text = str.trim();
      const myArray = text.split(" ");
      let mot ="";
      let finalStr = ""
      for(let i=0; i< myArray.length; i++)
        {
          mot = myArray[i];
          mot = mot.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mot.slice(1);
          finalStr =finalStr + mot;
        }
      if(finalStr.length >140){return false;}
      else {return "#"+finalStr;}
    }
}
```

This is the error I got:

> Expected an empty string to return false: expected '#' to equal false

I don't understand why I get this error, as I have included the empty string check.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- The result will *also* be the empty string when the input consists of only spaces. So *first* trim the input, and only then test for the empty string
- The test on the length of the result is wrong, because you make it *before* adding the `#` symbol. So change the test to check `>= 140`.

Here is your code with those two issues corrected

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
   let text = str.trim(); // Do this first
   if (text == "") {return false;}
   else
     {
      const myArray = text.split(" ");
      let mot ="";
      let finalStr = ""
      for(let i=0; i< myArray.length; i++)
        {
          mot = myArray[i];
          mot = mot.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mot.slice(1);
          finalStr =finalStr + mot;
        }
      if(finalStr.length >=140){return false;} // Take "#" into account
      else {return "#"+finalStr;}
    }
}
```

And here is a solution that uses a regular expression to extract the words, and uses `map` and `join` to build the result in one expression:

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
    const result = (str.trim().match(/\S+/g) ?? []).map(word =>
        word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
    ).join("");
    return !!result && result.length < 140 && "#" + result;
}
```